# Bind Enums to Checkboxs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on asp.net MVC project . I need to bind enum list to checkboxes ,I have list of enums  , which has the all the enums and other list which cotains only the selected enums . I return model which contains these two lists . How to bind it to the view .I implemented follow code but it's not working

```
public List<KioskOnboaringConfigurationFactors> SelectedKioskOnboaringConfigurationFactorsList { get; set; }

    public List<KioskOnboaringConfigurationFactors> AllKioskOnboaringConfigurationFactors { get; set; }



    @foreach (var g in Model.AllKioskOnboaringConfigurationFactorsList)
    {
        <li>
            <input type="checkbox"

                   @{if (Model.KioskOnboaringConfigurationFactorsList.Contains(g)) { <text> checked='checked' </text>  } } />
            <label >@g.ToString()</label>
        </li>
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking. What is your expected behavior and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to make a loop.

Comment: @Freggar  I updated my  queshtion

Comment: Great! Now please formulate your question.

Comment: See [this article](http://benfoster.io/blog/checkbox-lists-in-aspnet-mvc) and [source](https://github.com/benfoster/Fabrik.Common/blob/bb364373865ccae7187514dfdde33bdcc893b130/src/Fabrik.Common.Web/HtmlHelperExtensions.cs)

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need to store all enum values in a list, you can use [Enum.GetValues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues(v=vs.110).aspx).

Second you can use the [CheckBox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492737(v=vs.118).aspx) HTML helper.

```
@foreach (var g in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KioskOnboaringConfigurationFactors)).Cast<KioskOnboaringConfigurationFactors>())
{
    <li>
        @Html.CheckBox(g.ToString(), Model.SelectedKioskOnboaringConfigurationFactorsList.Contains(g))
        <label>@g.ToString()</label>
    </li>
}
```